# Posts with Urls that no longer exist?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

If a question is based completely on a URL that no longer exists, what should happen to the question?

Question Example:
[Can I create an Ads using those pictures without copyright issues?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/10926/can-i-create-an-ads-using-those-pictures-without-copyright-issues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no answers, I typically vote to close them as *unclear what you're asking*. You can also try linking to an archive from the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/). If there is an answer that I can reverse engineer the question then reconstruct the question otherwise vote as unclear or leave alone.

Comment: Trying to salvage the question seems like an appropriate course of action... linkrot is a problem :(

Comment: t@jimsug Yes, Thus link-only answers are prohibited.